# specifying a JAXB external binding for XSD sequence nodeName and choice/sequence nodeName

Tags: jaxb

I'm trying to eliminate "Element "___" shows up in more than one properties" with jxb external bindings on a xsd I don't maintain.

I can modify the XSD with the following that works:

```
    <xs:complexType name="credit">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element .../>
        <xs:element name="link" type="link" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:annotation> <xs:appinfo> <jxb:property name="linkElement"/> </xs:appinfo> </xs:annotation> 
        </xs:element>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:sequence>
                ...
                <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="link" type="link" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    ...
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
    ...
```

to create the sequence linkElement of type Link and sequence of choices:

```
    @XmlElement(name = "link")
protected List<Link> linkElement;
...
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "link", type = Link.class),
    ...
})
protected List<Object> linkAndBookmarkAndCreditWords;
```

but when I try a JAXB external binding file with the likes of:

```
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='credit']//xs:sequence//xs:element[@name='link']" >
        <jxb:property name="linkElement" />
    </jxb:bindings>
```

I get the error:

```
[ERROR] XPath evaluation of "...[@name='link']" results in too many (2) target nodes
```

How can I distinguish only the first "link" node as I do in the internal bindings?

Answer (score 1):

You XPath-expression is not precise enough. These `//` mean "anywhere below current node". This includes both of your `link` elements.

Try making your XPath-expression more precise, something along the lines:

```
xs:complexType[@name='credit']/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='link']
```